# Dividing polynomials with two unknowns and finding the unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The question I'm trying to solve is: when the function $f(x)= mx^3+(k-4)x^2+k^2x-7$ is divided by $(x+2)$ the remainder is $-111$. And when it is divided by $(x-4)$ the remainder is $489$. Determine all the possible values of $m$ and $k$.

So, I tried using the remainder theorem with both remainders like $P(-2)= -111$ and I plugged in $-2$ for $x$ and put $-111$ on the right side of the equal sign. I got the equation $k^2-2k+4m-44$. I got the same format for the second equation for $P(4)$. My question is: What do I do with two unknowns? I tried keeping the $k^2$ on the left side and moving everything to the right, to square root it but it got me nowhere.

Comment: Use latex for formulas please.

Comment: That's a system of two equations to solve for two unknonws. Try for example to eliminate one of variables between the equations, then you have one equation in one unknown to solve.

Comment: (1) what was the second equation you got ? (2) why you want to solve this ? (3) where was this taken from ? [[ this will enable giving Answers suitable to your Case ]]

Answer (score 2):

As you've suggested, we can apply the Remainder Theorem in each case. For the remainder upon division by $(x+2)$, we have
\begin{align}
-111 = f(-2) &= m(-2)^3 + (k-4)(-2)^2 + k^2(-2) - 7 \\
&= -8m + 4(k-4) - 2k^2 - 7
\end{align}
or
$$
4m + k^2 - 2k - 44 = 0. 
\tag{1}
$$

Analogously, for the remainder upon division by $(x-4)$, we have
\begin{align}
489 = f(4) &= m(4)^3 + (k-4)(4)^2 + k^2(4) - 7 \\
&= 64m + 16(k-4) + 4k^2 - 7
\end{align}
or
$$
16m + k^2 + 4k - 140 = 0. 
\tag{2}
$$

Subtracting Equation $(1)$ from $(2)$ yields $12m + 6k = 96$ or, with an eye towards substituting back into Equation $(1)$,
$$
4m = 32 - 2k. 
\tag{3}
$$

Now, Equation $(1)$ looks like
$$
(32 - 2k) + k^2 - 2k - 44 = 0 
$$
or
$$
k^2 - 4k - 12 = 0. 
$$

This quadratic equation has two solutions, namely
$$
k = -2 
\quad\text{or}\quad 
k = 6.
$$

Substituting back into Equation $(3)$, these correspond to
$$
m = 9 
\quad\text{or}\quad 
m = 5, 
$$
respectively.

Putting this all together, the only solutions are
$$
(m, k) = (9, -2) 
\quad\text{or}\quad 
(m, k) = (5, 6), 
$$
yielding the cubic polynomials
$$
f(x) = 9x^3 - 6x^2 + 4x - 7
$$
or
$$
f(x) = 5x^3 + 2x^2 + 36x - 7.
$$

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative approach, based on $P(-2) = -111$, $P(4) = 489$, and also $P(0) = -7$, the unique quadratic [interpolation polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Interpolation_theorem) through the $3$ points is $Q(x) = 12 x^2 + 76 x - 7$.

$P(x)-Q(x)$ is a cubic with leading coefficient $m$ which must vanish at $x=-2,0,4$, so:
$$
\begin{align}
P(x) &= Q(x) + m\,x(x+2)(x-4)
\\ &= m x^3 - 2 (m - 6) x^2 + 4 (19 - 2 m) x - 7
\end{align}
$$

Identifying coefficients against $P(x) = mx^3+(k-4)x^2+k^2x-7$:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
-2(m-6) &= k - 4
\\ 4 (19 - 2 m) &= k^2
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Eliminating $k$ between the two equations:

$$
4 (19 - 2 m) = \big(4-2(m-6)\big)^2 \;\;\iff\;\; m^2 - 14 m + 45 = 0 \;\;\iff\;\; m \in \{5, 9\}
$$